# Can't get to validate my xml agains xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

i'm trying to validate a simple xml file against an XSD but the validator is always telling me

'Cvc-elt.1: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'shipmentCreationRequest'.. Line '3', Column '36'.'

i did search on SO and tried several solutions bu nothing seems to work and resolve my problem ...
Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Test xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xsi:schemaLocation="Request.xsd" >
 </Test>
```

Here is the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Request" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Request" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <element name="Test"></element>
</schema>
```

Thanks for helping,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your actual error message was probably this:

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Test'.
```

Change your XML to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="http://www.example.org/Request"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/Request Request.xsd" >
</Test>
```

And change your XSD to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Request"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Request"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="Test"></element>
</schema>
```

Comment: Yes it was this, i changed it at the end for more simplicity ;) thank you very much for you time and answering for my problem .. it works perfectly.